# How to open and close a sockjs connection from client side?

Tags: sockjs

Currently, my client side connection opens when I refresh the page and closes when I close/refresh the tab.

I know I can close the connection from server side but I can't find it in the documentation to do so from the client side.

I want to be able to open a new connection on clicking a button, and closing the current connection on clicking another dom button.

How can I open or close a connection from the client side?

I basically want to do this;

> ```
>     div.col-md-6
>         div.btn-group.pull-right
>             button#button-newConnection.btn.btn-lg.btn-success(type='button', onclick="newConnection()") New Connection
>             button#button-closeConnection.btn.btn-lg.btn-danger(type='button', onclick="closeConnection()") Close Connection
> ```

```
function openConnection () {
    sock.connect();
}

function closeConnection () {
    sock.end();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sock.js follows HTML5 Websockets API as closely as possible. Just use `.close()` on the *Sock.js* object:

```
function closeConnection () {
    sock.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. I thought sock.close only worked from server side.

Comment: Well, it was not indeed in the documentation, so I think this question will help others. Have a nice day :)